# rake - How to execute a task with environment variables from inside another task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I want to emulate the command `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate` from inside another task.
I don't want this change of variable affecting the after tasks/bash commands, so "hard setting" the environment variable is not a option.
I couldn't find how to do it with `Rake::Task['task_name'].invoke`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do the job:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
```

Changing ENV from inside Ruby does not affect the parent shell - it is just a copy that has already been loaded into Ruby.